# Dynamically add a web component to a div

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I started with the generating click-counter example. I made the click-counter into a library which I then imported into my main file. The click-counter component can be added manually by putting the appropriate HTML into the web page before running the program. However, I've been unable to find a way to dynamically add the click-counter web component to a div. My attempts have either ended in "Aw, snap!" errors or simply with nothing happening.

The click-counter (xclickcounter.dart):

```dart
library clickcounter;
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

class CounterComponent extends WebComponent {
  int count = 0;

  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

The main HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css">

    <!-- import the click-counter -->
    <link rel="components" href="xclickcounter.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test1</h1>

    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <div is="x-click-counter" id="click_counter" count="{{startingCount}}"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="test1.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main file:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'xclickcounter.dart';

// initial value for click-counter
int startingCount = 5;

void main() {
  // no error for adding an empty button
  var button = new ButtonElement();
  query('#sample_container_id').append(button);

  // doesn't work (gives "Aw, snap!" in Dartium)
  query('#sample_container_id').append(new CounterComponent());

  // Nothing happens with this code. Nothing appears.
  // But I promise this same thing was giving Aw, Snap 
  // for a very similar program
  final newComponentHtml = '<div is="x-click-counter"></div>';
  query('#sample_container_id').appendHtml(newComponentHtml);
}
```

I tried added an empty constructor to click-counter but it still crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.
See the example (not mine) at https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/blob/master/test/data/input/component_created_in_code_test.html and let me know if it works for you.

TL;DR:

```
void main() {
  var element = query('#sample_container_id');
  appendComponentToElement(element, new CounterComponent() );
}

void appendComponentToElement(Element element, WebComponent component) {
  component.host = new DivElement();
  var lifecycleCaller = new ComponentItem(component)..create();
  element.append(component.host);
  lifecycleCaller.insert();
}
```

There's more info at my web-ui@dartlang.org post: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/web-ui/hACXh69UqG4/discussion

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi. This solved my problem. I was going to post the code as a new answer but I wanted you to get the points so maybe you could edit yours, appending the code. Then I'll mark it as the answer.